# ORACLE SQL- Number of Days between 2 dates

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I need help with getting the number of days between 2 dates in ORACLE SQL. If the HOSP_DISCH_TIME and HOSP_ADMSN_TIME are on the same day then it should return 0(zero). The dates are in 09-MAY-11 (DD-MMM-YY) format.

Here is my code -

```
 select HOSP_DISCH_TIME, HOSP_ADMSN_TIME, (HOSP_DISCH_TIME- 
 HOSP_ADMSN_TIME)as 
 Days 
 from PAT_ENC_HSP;
```

Thanks much!
JH

Comment: *The dates are in 09-MAY-11 (DD-MMM-YY) format* - so `HOSP_DISCH_TIME` and `HOSP_ADMSN_TIME` are `varchar2` columns, not `date` columns?

Answer (score 1):

```
select HOSP_DISCH_TIME, HOSP_ADMSN_TIME,
       trunc(HOSP_DISCH_TIME - HOSP_ADMSN_TIME) as Days 
from PAT_ENC_HSP;
```

Answer (score 0):

convert it on date format and subtract

```
 select HOSP_DISCH_TIME, HOSP_ADMSN_TIME, TO_DATE(HOSP_DISCH_TIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD') -  
           TO_DATE(HOSP_ADMSN_TIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as  Days 
 from PAT_ENC_HSP;
```